# Fixed Point Iterations on $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: numerical-methods, notation, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Say I have two nonlinear equations of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
= f(u,v) =
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(u,v) \\ f_2(u,v)
\end{bmatrix},
\tag*{(1)}
$$
where $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$ and I want to find fixed points $u^{\star}$ and $v^{\star}$ (assuming they exist). To compute them numerically, we can write the equations above as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{k+1} \\ v_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(u_k,v_k) \\ f_2(u_k,v_k)
\end{bmatrix},
\tag*{(2)}
$$
for $k = 1,2,\dots$, and iterate until the mismatches between successive $u_k$ and $v_k$ are sufficiently small. This method results in the following pseudocode:

```
k = 1; converged = false;
while converged == false
    u[k+1] = f_1(u[k], v[k]);
    v[k+1] = f_2(u[k], v[k]);
    if max(u[k+1] - u[k], v[k+1] - v[k]) < tolerance
        converged = true;
    end
    k += 1;
end
```

However, I can empirically get a faster convergence if in the calculation of $v_{k+1}$, I use the new $u_{k+1}$ instead of $u_k$. Then $(2)$ becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{k+1} \\ v_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(u_k,v_k) \\  {f_2(u_{\color{red}{ k + 1 }},v_k)}
\end{bmatrix}.
\tag*{(3)}
$$

**Questions**

1. Is $(3)$ a well-defined/standard expression for what I do numerically, based on the original $(1)$? If not, is there a standard way to express this sort of "joint" iterations of two variables?
2. More importantly, given that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable on their respective domains, if I use the Jacobian to evaluate whether $f_1$ and $f_2$ are contractions using $(1)$, does the result apply to the numerical implementation of $(3)$?

I hope MSE is the appropriate place to post this question, if not, please let me know/migrate it. Thanks!

Comment: A fixed point of this function is a pair, $(u,v).$ $u^*$ and $v^*$ are not both fixed points, but together, they can form one fixed point.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah ok, that makes sense. It's just that in my particular problem, I can explicitly work with $f_1$ and $f_2$ individually, and manipulate the original equation $g(u,v) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to become $u = f_1(u,v)$ and $v = f_2(u,v)$.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing,
in your pseudo-code,
you should take the
max of the
absolute value of those differences.

To get estimates of
the rate of convergence
of your two iterations,
assume an Taylor expansion of
$f(u+a, v+b)
\approx f(u, v)+a \dfrac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}\mid_{x=u, y=v}
+b \dfrac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}\mid_{x=u, y=v}
$
and do this at the fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the absolute value there but had it in my actual code. And I probably should've clarified, I want to compute the Jacobian and check the magnitude of each eigenvalue and see if it is strictly less than $1$, which if true then shows contractivity. But in the implementation I necessarily have to discretize the variables, and having the update of $v_{k+1}$ depend on $v_{k}$ and the new $u_{k+1}$ rather than the current $u_{k}$ seems to complicate things a little bit... or not, I could be overthinking this.